# how to chnage the ListViewItems default colors when mouse is over in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

> hi i want to change the default mouse over color of ListViewItems in WPF and i tried this code to change the default mouse over color here is my code

```
 <ListView x:Name="lv"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          BorderBrush="Transparent"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          Margin="0,20,0,0"
                          >
                    
                    
                    
                    <!--home-->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Style="{StaticResource lv_font}"
                                  Height="60" MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter"
                                  >
                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230"
                                    Margin="-6,0,0,0"
                                    Height="60"
                                    >

                            <Image Source="/Assert/alarms_home.ico" 
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   />
                            
                            <TextBlock Text="خانه"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       
                                       />

                        </StackPanel>
                        
                        
                        <!--tooltip-->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_home"
                                     Content="خانه"
                                     Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                        
                    </ListViewItem>
                    
                    <!--alarms-->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Style="{StaticResource lv_font}"
                                  Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                  Height="60"
                                  MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter"
                                  >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230"
                                    Margin="-6,0,0,0"
                                    Height="60"
                                    >

                            <Image Source="/Assert/icons8_alarm_on_1.ico" 
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            
                            <TextBlock Text="یادداشت ها"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       
                                       />

                        </StackPanel>


                        <!--tooltip-->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_alarms"
                                     Content="یادداشت ها"
                                     Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>
                        
                    </ListViewItem>
                    
                    
                    <!--add notes-->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Style="{StaticResource lv_font}"
                                  Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                  Height="60"
                                  MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter"
                                  >
                        
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230"
                                    Margin="-6,0,0,0"
                                    Height="60"
                                    >

                            <Image Source="/Assert/alarm_add_1.ico" 
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="افزودن"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       />

                        </StackPanel>

                        <!--tooltip-->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_add"
                                     Content="افزودن"
                                     Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                    </ListViewItem>
                    
                    
                    <!--about us-->
                    <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Style="{StaticResource lv_font}"
                                  Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                  Height="60"
                                  MouseEnter="ListViewItem_MouseEnter"
                                  >
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Width="230"
                                    Margin="-6,0,0,0"
                                    Height="60"
                                    >

                            <Image Source="/Assert/icons8_about_5.ico" 
                                   Stretch="None"
                                   Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   />
                            
                            <TextBlock Text="درباره ما"
                                       Margin="50,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       />

                        </StackPanel>


                        <!--tooltip-->
                        <ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                            <ToolTip x:Name="tt_about"
                                     Content="درباره ما"
                                     Style="{StaticResource tt_style}"/>

                        </ListViewItem.ToolTip>

                    </ListViewItem>

               




                    <!--style-mouse-over for list-->
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                            <Setter Property="Template">

                                <Setter.Value>

                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

                                        <Border x:Name="Bd1"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                                >
                                            <ContentPresenter
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                                />

                                        </Border>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                          <MultiTrigger>

                                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" 
                                                                    Value="True"/>

                                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

                                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                                        TargetName="Bd1"
                                                        Value="#B5C1B4"/>

                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                                        TargetName="Bd1"
                                                        Value="#B5C1B4"/>



                                          </MultiTrigger>

                                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                                    </ControlTemplate>

                                </Setter.Value>

                            </Setter>

                        </Style>

                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                </ListView>
```

> But it is not worked, I did not get any error but it is not changed the default color if you have any other idea or this code is wrong please tell me.
> Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine. You could however replace the MultiTrigger by an ordinary Trigger like `<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">`

Comment: i did it but it is not worked i edit my question and write my all listview code, maybe i have problem in my listview

Comment: How do you expect the ItemContainerStyle to be applied to ListViewItems when you explicitly set their Style? As a note, use the simpler ListBox when you don't set the View property of a ListView.

Comment: I am new in WPF and i do not know how to do it, if you have a site or video for tutorial please tell me.

Comment: oh i find what is the problem, i setting the style two times for list view items first inside the list view item tag and then in  ListView.ItemContainerStyle i remove the first one and it is worked.